Consistency in the case of 2 nodes going down simultaneously in 5 node cluster
Let's we have a 5 nodes cluster(one master + 4 slaves). Application is doing writes with min quoram on 3 nodes (master + 2 slave) to ensure consistency in the case of node failure.
For ease of understanding let's assume

5 nodes being A (master), B, C, D, E.
B,C,D,E are continuously replicating from A.
replication speed is B > C> D> E

In this example if min write quorum is 3 nodes, then a write is acknowledged only if it is replicated with B and C (since replication to D and E is slowest)
In case node A goes down, remaining 4 nodes will determine what is the max offset that is present in atleast 2 replicas. B might have some records that are not yet replicated to C (because B is replicating faster than C). Hence once leader election is done, during reconciliation, B would need to drop those records for ensuring consistency.
But what happens when both A and C goes down simultaneously? Since node B will have records which C and D does not, how to determine the consistent state of system?
This problem is not specific to any datastore, but all the data stores that have master slave model with quoram based writes (for example mongodb)
